# Google Chrome custom search engine for secure Wikipedia through Google search

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, google-search

I have this custom search engine set up in Google Chrome:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aen.wikipedia.org+%s&btnI=1
```

It searches Google for `site:en.wikipedia.org {query}`, and the `btnI=1` is for *I'm Feeling Lucky*, so it automatically redirects to the first result. I like this better than using Wikipedia's search function directly because I can misspell my search, or leave a word out, or just search for some keywords, and I still get what I'm looking for right away.

What I'd like is for it to use Wikipedia's secure gateway:

```
https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/
```

It's easy enough to set up a custom search engine that uses the secure version of Wikipedia's search function directly, but I can't figure out how to correctly incorporate it into my version going through Google. Nothing I've tried works.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=site:https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen+%s&btnI=745
```

Comment: That's one of the things that I tried, but it doesn't work for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: @gdejohn yes, it works as expected! With keyword `sse` mapped to search engines typing sse, hitting tab and entering `finland` as the search term results in this query being fired `https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=site:https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen+finland&btnI=745` which then redirects to `https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Finland`

Comment: `Finland` works, but for some reason, lots of searches don't automatically redirect, like `Norway`. Adding the `sourceid` parameter with value `navclient` fixes that. I also figured out that you can do site search as a parameter, rather than cluttering up the query with it: `https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&btnI=1&as_sitesearch=https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en&q=%s`. Unfortunately, some searches that work for the regular Wikipedia URL don't work for the secure portal at all (no results come up, so there's nothing to redirect to). For example, `google plus`.

Answer (score -1):

This does the trick for me:

- https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Special:Search?search=%s

Comment: As I said in the question, I want to go straight to Google's top result from Wikipedia so that I can misspell my search, or leave a word out, or just search for some keywords, and still get what I'm looking for right away.

Comment: In that case, I apologize.  That point was buried deep within the description; I must have skimmed over it.  I edited the title to account for this so that it's much more explicit.